# Git: Testing commits without pushing

Tags: git

We have two separate teams that are working on the same product: design and verification.
Designer adds features, run a simple test to check that design compiles and a very basic test is running and need to pass it to the verification team.
My question and concern is: how designer can easily and safely pass commits without pushing them to the server? Otherwise it could be a very long commits history which I want to avoid.
If designer can work with verification team without pushing changes to the server all those commits can be squashed to a single one and then pushed.

Comment: Look at branches. Work on the same branch between both teams, then squash when merging to master.

Comment: There's a trivially simple rule: to *test* a commit you must *have* that commit. Who is doing the testing? He (or she or it) must have the commit. Hence there must be some communications channel between developer and tester. That does not have to be "the" server, anyone can be a server, there is only a "the" server if you say "that server there, that is *the* server". (And: branch names do not matter, only *commits* matter. For push/pull you do need to attach *some* name, at least temporarily, of course.)

Comment: I want to eliminate history pollution by an iteration between design and QA.

Answer (score 3):

> without pushing them to the server

With Git, you don't have to limit yourself to "the" (one) server.

You can add as a remote *another* server, dedicated for QA testing, where designer can push.
A post-receive hook can then:

- pass some test
- reject (reset) the commit which has just been pushed if those tests fail
- or push that same commit to the actual server if those tests pass.

In other words, the QA server acts as a gateway between the designer commits and the actual server.

Another approach is to push those commits to the (one) server, but in a dedicated branch, merge by the verification team to master of the tests pass.

Comment: But all these commits still be visible in the history. And I won't be able to squash them.

Comment: @Michael the post-receive hook can squash them for you (if you want: that hook is a script: you can make it do whatever you need) on a dedicated branch (if the tests pass) and push that for you.

Answer (score 1):

You absolutely don't have to restrict `commits` using `git`. That is not the purpose of it. One of the best practices says [**Commit Early And Often**](https://sethrobertson.github.io/GitBestPractices/#commit). If you want to have some order in your repository, you must use `branches`.

In your case, you can have a `branch` for the design of a feature, and when that feature is finished, the design team can run tests an close the `branch`. Doing that, the verification team will see that a feature as being merged, and then will verify it.

There is a really good extension of `git` that makes this work easier called [`git-flow.`](https://danielkummer.github.io/git-flow-cheatsheet/) Maybe that is what you are really looking for.

Comment: I agree. But I don't want the history have a lot of iterations between design and QA.

Answer (score 1):

If there is a legitimate reason to want to pass commits around without pushing to a central server, you can look into [`git-bundle`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-bundle), which allows you to package up one or more commits and ship them directly as a single file.

**Edit**: If the OP really wants to avoid both rewriting history (even on a separate branch) and having extra commits, one possible solution (not generally recommended) is to not create commits at all, and simply pass patch files around.

1. The developer makes whatever change they want and then runs `git diff > MyChange.patch`. He emails this to QA.
2. QA checks out the same commit as the developer, and runs `patch -p1 < MyChange.patch`. The QA now has the same state as the developer, without any git commits being created.

Comment: Isn't it the same as push/pull but without server? If I squash commits later the QA will not be able to use their workspace anymore.

Comment: @Michael, Just to be clear, are you aware that if you have a shared branch with only the QA such as `test`, they can always do a `git reset --hard origin/test` to make their history match yours after you squash? They will be able to use their workspace again after such a command.